# Bash script or the like to erase env values that host secrets once used to initialized app in a kubernetes container

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, shell, environment-variables, kubernetes

I have a flask app that runs in a kube cluster. It does all the right things by using kube secrets to set the env values required to initialize the application.  There are some env values I suspect only need to be "read once"; those that fire-up db and other services.  It made me wonder...

When I was debugging the container, it was amazing to see how many secrets are available in the container's environment. Granted, in this debug setup, I use a "sleep for infinity" type of command that allows me to debug and manually fire-up the app.  I'm insufficiently experienced with shell scripting to know if it's at all feasible to have a script that both fires-up the flask app, then at least changes the env secret values to some "dummy" value once the app is up-and-running.  I'm also insufficiently familiar with kube to know if my logic is flawed.

In a kube setting there are `initContainers` that solve related issues, prior to the start of the main app (e.g., used to set permissions and config values).

How might I think about a post-start "hygiene" process without stopping the app?

1. Is the idea "oxymoronic" in a way? (in other words, "makes no sense")
2. Perhaps if I ran a bash script that fires-up the flask app (needs to be foreground I believe to operate in a kube cluster(?)), but changes env for "other" shells? (i.e., any shell made available to anything that tries to use the system)
3. [x] Can a shell script be used to change the env values of another process? **No** (@muru)
4. Is it perhaps useful/possible to do so from the flask app?
5. Feasible or not, do any of these approaches fail to *further* protect my secrets

Comment: I'm inclined to go with yes for (1). Environment variables are inherited by or set for child processes. Which component in this system is responsible for setting these variables? Any child process of that will then have access to them. What do you mean by "other shells" in (2)? (3) is a straight "no". (4) may make sense if you're worried about RCE vulnerabilities in the flask app.

Comment: @muru Thank you for your response. I updated the question based on your input.